# How to customize Nginx http module

Tags: http, nginx

I'm trying to parse only the http part separately in the nginx file and deliver it to the AWS sagemaker part, so please tell me how to deliver this part!

And what setting files, what parts should I touch and how should I set the function?

It has no idea...

'''nginx
http {
lua_package_path "/path/to/lua-scripts/?.lua;;";

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_server_name;

    location /your_endpoint {
        access_by_lua_block {
            -- Lua 스크립트에서 HTTP 헤더를 파싱하고 추출하는 부분
            local user_agent = ngx.var.http_user_agent
            local authorization = ngx.var.http_authorization
            -- 필요한 다른 헤더도 추출할 수 있습니다.

            -- SageMaker로 전송할 HTTP 요청을 생성
            local request_body = "User-Agent: " .. user_agent .. "\nAuthorization: " .. authorization
            local response = ngx.location.capture("/sagemaker_endpoint", {
                method = ngx.HTTP_POST,
                body = request_body,
            })

            -- SageMaker 응답을 클라이언트에 반환
            ngx.say(response.body)
        }
    }

    location /sagemaker_endpoint {
        internal;
        proxy_pass https://sagemaker-url;  -- SageMaker URL로 설정
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

}

'''

This part is from Chat GPT